# How to get all the signatures of multi sub or build-ins?

Tags: raku

I defined a `multi sub` which has two signatures:

```
multi sub mie(Str $s, Int $i) { $s x $i }
multi sub mie(Int $s, Int $i) { ... }
say &mie.signature; # ;; Mu | is raw)
```

I want to get the signature of this `multi sub`, but the above result is not what i expected.

As the document said, [contains](https://docs.perl6.org/routine/contains) is a multi method which has 4 signatures:

```
multi method contains(Str:D: Cool:D $needle)
multi method contains(Str:D: Str:D $needle)
multi method contains(Str:D: Cool:D $needle, Int(Cool:D) $pos)
multi method contains(Str:D: Str:D $needle, Int:D $pos)
```

But when i try to get the signature of [contains](https://docs.perl6.org/routine/contains):

```
say "a string".^methods.pairs.values[8].value.signature;
```

It only output one signature:

```
(Str: | is raw)
```

In the REPL, when i call the `contains` method without argument, it output the following error:

```
> "a string".contains()
Cannot resolve caller contains(Str: ); none of these signatures match:
    (Str:D: Cool:D $needle, *%_)
    (Str:D: Str:D $needle, *%_)
    (Str:D: Cool:D $needle, Cool:D $pos, *%_)
    (Str:D: Str:D $needle, Int:D $pos, *%_)
  in block <unit> at <unknown file> line 1
```

That indicate that `contains` method indeed has 4 signatures! I want to know is there any methods that can output all the [signature](https://docs.perl6.org/routine/signature) of a method/multi method?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try `"a string".^lookup('contains').candidates».signature`

`.^lookup('contains')` will find the [`Method`](https://docs.perl6.org/type/Method)

`.candidates` will list the multi [candidates](https://docs.perl6.org/type/Method#(Routine)_method_candidates)

`.signature` will give you the [`Signature`](https://docs.perl6.org/type/Signature) for each one.

Output:

`((Str:D: Cool:D $needle, *%_) (Str:D: Str:D $needle, *%_) (Str:D: Cool:D $needle, Cool:D $pos, *%_) (Str:D: Str:D $needle, Int:D $pos, *%_))`

You can use it for your `multi sub` too:

`say &mie.candidates».signature;`

Answer (score 11):

As a complement to Curt's answer:

```
proto foo (;; Mu | is raw) {*}               # proto(;; Mu | is raw)

multi foo ($a)             { }               # multi($a)
multi foo (Int $a)         { }               # multi(Int $a)

multi foo ($a,$b)          { }               # multi($a, $b)
multi foo (Int $a,$b)      { }               # multi(Int $a, $b)

say 'proto', .signature for &foo;            # displays 1 line
say 'multi', .signature for &foo.candidates; # displays 4 lines
```

I've shown the results of the `say`s alongside their respective routines.

If you call `foo ...` where `foo` is a multiple dispatch routine (same with `.foo`) then, at least semantically, you're actually calling a [`proto`](https://docs.perl6.org/syntax/proto) declared for that name that then (normally) redispatches to the best fitting `multi` with the same name.

(If you call methods on `&foo`, rather than `foo`, then you're calling them on the `Routine` object for that `proto`.)

A manually declared `proto` provides complete control of the dispatch process. It can make a cup of tea and then use Common Lisp dispatch semantics and then fiddle with the result. Or whatever else it wants to do.

If one or more `multi`s are declared without explicitly declaring a `proto` then a default `proto` is automatically generated. I've manually declared a `proto` to ground the following:

- The [`;;`](https://docs.perl6.org/type/Signature#Long_names) in the signature excludes parameters in the `proto` sig from being relevant for "winning" the initial dispatch to it -- no matter what, the `proto` "wins" the initial dispatch and gets all the arguments;
- The `Mu` parameter type constraint explicitly gives the broadest possible type to the [`|` parameter](https://docs.raku.org/type/Signature#Capture_parameters), which parameter binds to the entire list of arguments passed to it (in a [`Capture`](https://docs.raku.org/type/Capture)), and the [`is raw`](https://docs.raku.org/type/Signature#index-entry-trait__is_raw) means the capture is received in its "raw" form (I currently don't understand what this trait does here; I had thought a `Capture` is by definition a raw, unprocessed list of arguments).
- The body then dispatches to the next same named routine (that's what the `{*}`  does).

Answer (score 2):

I made the `P6Repl::Helper` module a while ago for this purpose.